# Interactive Input Editing and History Substitution (Python Documentation_Ch14)

Tags: python, input, documentation, history, substitution

Scoured the net to find an answer on [this doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interactive.html):

> Some versions of the Python interpreter support editing of the current
>   input line and history substitution, similar to facilities found in
>   the Korn shell and the GNU Bash shell. This is implemented using the
>   GNU Readline library, which supports various styles of editing. This
>   library has its own documentation which we won’t duplicate here.

- Read about Unix but **what is this operation called editing of the
  current input line**? (Examples, Resources for Python or a simple
  example wourd be great)
- **History Substitution**... what is that maybe a simple example? Documentation touches on the issue as a know field and doesn't provide any insight on it.

Also cannot crack the line:

> Completion of variable and module names is automatically enabled at
>   interpreter startup so that the Tab key invokes the completion
>   function; it looks at Python statement names, the current local
>   variables, and the available module names.

Can anybody provide a simple line explaining this line.

Comment: Its just `tab` auto completion. Same as if you type code in an IDE and use `tab` to autofill.  What part in particular confuses you?

Comment: Editing the current input line just means it changes the current line. Open command prompt (or terminal), run some commands, then hit up arrow. That is editing the current input line.

Comment: ohhhhh and i can edit which are appering somehow MY GOD why dont they say it simply

Comment: How are the variables/module names completed? Does he mean activated? Tab Key invokes the completion function of which ... how is a variable ...completed a variable is set! In what sense? @Error-SyntacticalRemorse

Comment: Thousand apologies i plowed through all of the documentation but i couldnt gap this knowledge vacuum for days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing the current input line is common practice.

For example if I use command prompt and do:

```
cd C:\Us
```

and hit `Tab` it will auto fill to:

```
cd C:\Users\
```

It just edited the current input line.

Similarly look up history does the same thing. If I do the following in command prompt:

```
> color b --> [Enter]
> # Now I have an empty command line
[Up Arrow]
> color b # Command prompt will fill the current line with what I just used.
```

Python can do the same thing by looking up variables and packages:

```
>>> import foobar
>>> fo [TAB] --> >>> foobar
```

Python auto filled `fo` to `foobar` because it knew I imported it by reading through my code.
It can do the same for variables (by reading the python code to find variables you defined).

```
>>> temp_var = 2
>>> te [TAB] --> >>> temp_var
```

Comment: If i only knew that the answer was so simple. I spent a whole day reading about Unix systems. I thank u and i wish a giant cookie appear in your way

Comment: Did u meant cd *8 and not cd Us? that how i got uners